# Dedupe rule to reject record rather than creating new record

Tags: duplicate-contacts, dedupe-rules

i understand that you can use the dedupe rule to identify matching record to merge a new record or to create a new record altogether.  Is there a means to reject the new record altogether if a match is not found?  For example, if i use this rule in a profile form submission, it will only allow entries that already has a record in the CIVICRM system due to a match but will reject the entry if no match is found.  Thanks.

Comment: agree with Fabian that an approach that helps identify if the user is already in your system before the form is submitted somehow- what CMS are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not aware of anything in CiviCRM core that would allow you to do so. Depending on your use case you could consider setting up forms that can only be used by authentictaed users.